# How can I use lambda operation for assigning one attribute of entity?

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I have a code like this:

```
 return new Match
                {
                    Id =  DataHelper.GetLong(dataReader, "MatchID") > 0 ?
                         DataHelper.GetLong(dataReader, "MatchID") : 
                          DataHelper.GetLong(dataReader, "ID")
                }
```

In here I want to do like this to increase performance:

```
Id =  DataHelper.GetLong(dataReader, "Match");
Id =  Id > 0 ?  Id   :  DataHelper.GetLong(dataReader, "ID")
```

How can I do this in code above with lambda notation?

Edit: I agree that we can not use lambda notation for these codes. Defining other function  will be the proper way for my question.

Comment: what does this have to do with lambda?

Comment: Your first and second example don’t really match: in the first you have `Match`, `MatchID` and `ID`, whereas in the second you only have `Match` and `ID`. That being said I don’t see how example 1 can be improved performance-wise if it’s three different items.

Comment: @Nkosi yes we dont use lambda in here, it was my mistake

Comment: @ckuri  I edited question It should be   `Id =  DataHelper.GetLong(dataReader, "MatchID") > 0 ?
                         DataHelper.GetLong(dataReader, "MatchID") : 
                          DataHelper.GetLong(dataReader, "ID")`

Answer (score 1):

Extract your conditional login into a function, the call the function from the object initializer:

```cs
long GetMatchId(dataReader)
{
    var id = DataHelper.GetLong(dataReader, "Match");
    return (id > 0 ? id : DataHelper.GetLong(dataReader, "ID"));
}

return new Match {
    Id = GetMatchId(dataReader)
};
```

Comment: Thanks, this is the way! I am a bit shy for easy question